# Ghostscript /undefinedresource in findresource

Tags: ghostscript

I encounter the issue during pdf merging process by using ghostscript.

Error: /undefinedresource in findresource

Operand stack:

--dict:5/14(L)--   F0   22   --dict:6/6(L)--   --dict:6/6(L)--   MKQZSY+PalatinoLinotype   2437   CM30   CIDSystemInfo   --dict:12/13(ro)(L)--   CMap   --dict:12/13(ro)(L)--

Execution stack:

%interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1846   1   3   %oparray_pop   1845   1   3   %oparray_pop   1829   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   1   2   --nostringval--   %for_pos_int_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   %array_continue   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   %loop_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   1797   11   13   %oparray_pop   findresource   %errorexec_pop   --nostringval--   --nostringval--

Dictionary stack:

--dict:1150/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:75/200(L)--   --dict:75/200(L)--   --dict:106/127(ro)(G)--   --dict:285/300(ro)(G)--   --dict:22/25(L)--   --dict:4/6(L)--   --dict:21/40(L)--   --dict:1/1(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/1(ro)(G)--   --dict:6/15(L)--   --dict:38/38(ro)(G)--   --dict:16/25(ro)(G)--

Current allocation mode is local

Last OS error: 2

GPL Ghostscript 8.70: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

The used command is :

gs \

-sDEVICE=pdfwrite \

-dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress \

-o /sefas/temp/jercol1/bug_ghostScript/out.pdf \

-q ./in.pdf

The PalatinoLinoType seems to be embedded in the input pdf :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Le0mq.png

Unfortunaly, I can't share the pdf due to some confidential contracts.

I've tried to fix the problem by using a custom cidmap file, but without success.

I would like to understand what exactly is the source of the problem here, as the fonts seems to be embeded in the pdf.

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't share the file, then there's nothing much anyone can do to help you. The only thing I can think of is that you could try using a version of Ghostscript which is less than 9 years old!

The current version is 9.25.

Comment: Yes I understand. I was thinking that somebody could help about the error message itself. So i will check with the administrators if they can provide a more recent version of ghostscript. It's true that 9 years old is almost a legacy tool ;). Thank you for your answer. I will update the ticket if i get another result. Best regards

Comment: The error says that a request was made for a resource (a PostScript resource, such as font or CMap) which could not be satisfied. Some kinds of resources (eg Fonts, but not CIDFonts) can fall back to a default resource, but in this case that isn't apparently possible. Beyond that, I'm afraid the version is so old I can't really guess. Its likely that this is either a bug, or a missing feature. More recent versions of Ghostscript have a default for missing CIDFonts, for instance. You should really update, from a security POV if nothing else.

Comment: I have tested with a more recent version (9.18) available on my desktop running windows. Despite errors detected on the pdf, ghostscript is able to generate a correct output. Thank for your explanations. Update ghostscript to the last available version seems to be the best thing to do.

Comment: Errors in the PDF would explain it. We constantly have to add work-arounds to deal with PDF files that are in some sense broken.